# Matlab function to create duplicate obs based on the value of a string variable

Tags: matlab

In my dataset, I have a variable which takes values like abc-ABC or abc-def-ABC (i.e., one or more lower-case codes and one upper-case code). I would like to (1) count the number of lower-case codes and capture this no. in a new variable (2) multiply the initial observation by this number (e.g., for abc-def-ABC, I would want 2 obs). Can anyone help?

Comment: Yes. Please give an example and I'd be happy to.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand what you want with (2) but... To count the occurrences, can't you just

```
code = 'abc-def-ABC';
observations = numel(regexp(code, '[a-z]+-'))
```